# How to most compactly implement the code on DRF ORM

Tags: python, django, orm, django-rest-framework, django-orm

```
def read_rate(self, id):

    cursor = self.db.cursor()

    cursor.execute('SELECT volume FROM rate WHERE cur_id = ' + str(id) + ' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10')
    volume = cursor.fetchall()

    cursor.execute('SELECT rate FROM rate WHERE cur_id = ' + str(id) + 'ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1')
    (get,) = cursor.fetchone()
    rate = str(get)
    average = str(sum([float(x[0]) for x in volume])/len(volume))

    cursor.close()
    return {'rate': rate, 'average_volume': average}
```

Need to implement the code on DRF ORM, where queryset will return 'cur id', 'last rate' and 'average volume in the last 10 days'

Model

```
class Rate(models.Model):
    cur = models.ForeignKey(Cur, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    rate = models.FloatField()
    volume = models.FloatField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.cur

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-id']
```

and how I tried to implement

```
class RateView(ListAPIView):


    serializer_class = RateSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Rate.objects.values(
            cur__id__in=[self.kwargs['id']]).order_by(
                '-id')[:10].annotate(Avg('volume'), 'rate', self.kwargs['id'])
```

Comment: Hi Mike, could you post up your `models.py` file for the "Rate" model ... or is this not modelled in your application (i.e., are you connecting to an external DB source?)

Comment: Ignore me, you have!

Answer (score 0):

So, it looks like you have your base queryset setup slightly off.

I'm not sure you need to order by the ID, because you ae filtering on one id. So every ID in the retruned filtered `QuerySet<>` object will be the same - so technically, it's already ordered.

The `values()` method is a way to extract the `QuerySet<>` for iterative manipulation ... so you will need to filter first on the `cur__id` being equal to `self.kwargs['id']`.

Next, extract only the values you want - which looks to me like `id`, `rate` and `volume` (needed for the proceeding annotation).

Then, utilise the `Avg` aggregator as shown.

Then limit? (I think - I'm not sure if this works for less than 10 entries off hand).

So, all in all, I would implement it in this way:

```
class RateView(ListAPIView):

    serializer_class = RateSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Rate.objects.all()

    def list(self):
        queryset = self.get_queryset().filter(
            cur__id=self.kwargs['id']
        )

        queryset = queryset.values(
            'id',
            'rate', 
            'volume'
        ).annotate(
            average_volume=Avg('volume'),
        )[:10]

        ...
```

I've also changed up your base class method "`get_queryset()`" to return `all()` objects - the only filtering I would do on this level is very basic filtering, such as if the view was for showing all `female` Users (for whatever reason)...so a User.objects.filter(gender='female') would make sense as your base query to build from.

The point at which it is evaluated by the DB, is on the final `values()` call.